# What is Motorola Camera app's Photo naming convention?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, camera, motorola-moto-g2

The Images are saved as `IMG_yyyyMMdd_kkmmssSSS.jpg`

Here, the `yyyyMMdd` part in filenames matches the first half of the photo's EXIFDate/Time data.

Can anyone please help me out with figuring out the rest of the file name and how can I extract this from the photo's EXIF data?

Comment: Just curious, where did you get the info about the filename format?

Comment: @AndrewT. I decompiled the apk.

Answer (score 2):

The format follows the pattern used in [`DateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class from Java/Android. It's:

1. `IMG`: constant prefix for *Images*
2. `yyyyMMdd`: date

   - years (4-digit)
   - months (2-digit)
   - days (2-digit)
3. `kkmmssSSS`: time

   - hours (2-digit in 24-hour format, from 1-24)
   - minutes (2-digit)
   - seconds (2-digit)
   - milliseconds (3-digit)

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. 
However I have already figured this out. The app uses the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class in Java. What I still don't know is that how the values for `kkmmssSSS` is determined and additionally if it can be found in the photo's EXIF data. I am guessing that it denotes the *Date/Time Orignal* tag under EXIF. Would be nice if you or anyone else could confirm.

Comment: I wouldn't know if you hadn't mentioned it in the question. Could you put some example filenames on the question?  As for EXIF, I'm afraid I can't help with that since I don't have (photos from) Motorola devices.